# Confirmation before closing a C program

Tags: c, visual-studio, return, exit

I'm having trouble with asking for confirmation before closing a program in C. I am looking for the program to initiate the confirm exit loop when 0 is entered however the program currently closes immediately when 0 is entered instead of asking for confirmation.

```
else if (input == 0)//if they chose to exit

        {
printf("You have input 0, program is attempting to close, do you wish to continue? Press 0 for yes, any other number for no");
scanf_s ("%d", &secondinput);


        if (secondinput == 0)
        {

            return;
        }

        else if (secondinput !=0)
        {
            print_menu(1);
            scanf_s("%d", &input);
        }
```

I am guessing I am missing a more elegant solution to this I've tried a few things and just can't get it working.

Example of what is happening:
1 is entered which adds an integer to an array
integer to add is requested e.g. 8
upon pressing 0 the program is meant to state "do you wish to close, 0 for yes, any other integer for no"
however when 0 is pressed the program immediately closes.

Comment: Have you tried putting a break point on `if (secondinput == 0)` and looking at the value of `secondinput`?

Comment: How are `input` and `secondinput` declared? What types are they?

Comment: They are both integers.

Comment: if this is solved can you mark the answer that solved it, or answer it yourself?

Answer (score 1):

You can include a do while loop, and include the operations in them.

```
    do
    {
       */some operation */
       printf("\n enter an number to continue : (0 to stop) :")
       scanf("%d",&input);
     }while(input!=0);
```

The program will continue as long as input number is not equal to 0.

Comment: I will try this and see how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

One simple possibility is that stdin still contains a value waiting to be read (a zero specifically).  Assuming that the user did not type something like `0 0` (two inputs) at the console, then it seems likely that the problem lies in the code not shown. It may somehow not be reading from stdin in quite as you expect.

Comment: This was my thought too, but I have tried different inputs e.g. 1 1 1 0 and it still closes. I've also done a clean build and it hasn't helped.

Comment: @Grubbery:  If you can update your post with a complete example (hopefully short) that demonstrates the issue, that would probably lead to a quick resolution.

Comment: I've added an example of how it should work:
Example of what is happening: 1 is entered which adds an integer to an array integer to add is requested e.g. 8 upon pressing 0 the program is meant to state "do you wish to close, 0 for yes, any other integer for no" however when 0 is pressed the program immediately closes.

Comment: @Grubbery:  Sorry, I meant a complete *code* example (not what you are typing).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the rest of your code looks like, but I was able to get this code to work perfectly when typing in 1's and 0's, (I'm using visual studio 2008 with visual c++)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int arg, char** args)
{
    int input;
    int secondinput;

    while(1)
    { 
        printf("input: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &input);
        if (input == 1)
        {
            //dosomething
        }
        else if (input == 0)//if they chose to exit

        {
            printf("You have input 0, program is attempting to close, do you wish to continue? Press 0 for yes, any other number for no");
            scanf_s ("%d", &secondinput);


            if (secondinput == 0)
            {

                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```